# Windows Azure messages to connected clients

Tags: azure, push, publish-subscribe

I have to develop application which works with windows azure. Our requirement is clients(Windows service or console application) can connect to server(kind of subscribe) then waiting. server pushes messages to specific client time to time.

Could someone direct me in the right direction, or a tutorial will be helpful.

Comment: Go look at Service Bus options. You can do a sub/pub architecture there very well. Depending on your other needs, you can consider different options.

Comment: Thnaks for quick answer Would that allow me to work on windows (console and service )clients as well. I will check it out.

Comment: ServiceBus allows you to have 0-to-many people subscribed to the events. You can control if you want to only publish them to live listeners or if they pile up for when a listener comes back online (downtime/upgrades/outage/etc). All sorts of things are possible. Go read up on it and do a couple Hello World examples so you can ask better questions more specific to your needs. :-)

Comment: One thing,As i understand to retrieve notification all the clients has to request from the server. Is there any way server can push data to clients as this explain "http://www.pubnub.com/solutions/how-pubnub-works"

Comment: Thanks Jaxidian 4ur direction. I found good link and explained to me what i want. I will leave the link if any one want in future. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/SAC-862T